# extract year, month, day, from date field in a report?

Tags: reporting, formula, date

I was wondering if it would be possible when creating a report to have individual columns for each portion of a created date field (column for year, column for month, column for day)? I know I could create custom fields and use formulas to extract these portions, but I'm wondering if its possible to just do it directly in a report?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really.

You can kind of do this using a row level formula (can be created in lightning report from dropdown next to 'columns' text).

Year column can be created like so (formula output type = text):

```
 TEXT(YEAR(--date field goes here --))
```

But you only get one row level formula for each report, so you wouldn't be able to do it for year, month and day.

Comment: ah, that's too bad. i'll just make the custom fields then. thanks for the answer!